# Exclude lines ending with a specific word when redirecting output of shell command to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I intend to run a shell command that outputs hundreds of lines that end with the word 'OK'. I want to store this output to a file and do not want all those lines that end with the 'OK'. How would I do this?
Something like `command > output.txt --exclude_lines=*.OK` is what I was looking for.

Comment: That is what pipes are made for `command | grep -v 'OK' > output.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the word `OK` is supposed to be at the **end** of the line, you could do it by

```
your_command | grep -vw 'OK$' >output.txt
```

The `$` ensures that an OK inside the line is ignored, and the `-w` ensures that a line ending in i.e. *NOK* is not missed.